# Google Chrome Extensions Manifest 2 update

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store

I'm just wondering if there is a new way in manifest 2 to rewrite a sample app like this one.

http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples.html#4e35caa9742fb82dbd628892d23a781614f6eff6

I started to convert this into a manifest 2 app and ran into some issues.

```
bgPage.oauth.authorize(function() {
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'authorize' of undefined
  if (!bgPage.docs.length) {
    gdocs.getDocumentList();
  } else {
    gdocs.renderDocList();
  }
  util.scheduleRequest();
});

bgPage.oauth.sendSignedRequest(url, gdocs.processDocListResults, params);
```

For some reason in manifest2 the bgPad.oauth call is not valid anymore.

Is there a way to make this work again?

Comment: What error are you seeing in the console?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'authorize' of undefined

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ran into this same problem when I converted my own app to manifest version 2. Firstly, I just want to make sure you're aware that you need to remove all inline code, and place it inside separate script includes. For example, popup.html has a whole lot of inline code; I moved it inside a popup.js and put that where the inline code was. (This must be done on `background.html`, `popup.html`, and `chrome_ex_oauth.html`

Secondly, due to Google's further tightening of permissions allowed within apps and extensions, you'll need to add this in your manifest:

```
"web_accessible_resources": [
  "chrome_ex_oauth.html"
]
```

I've zipped up my modified version of the extension for your edification:
https://dl.dropbox.com/u/73603348/gdocs.zip